# PyQt5 QuickControls Material style

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qtquickcontrols

I'm experimenting with QuickControls with latest PyQt5 and trying to apply Material style via QML as explained [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-styles.html) and [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-material.html):

```
QQuickStyle::setStyle("Material");
```

But unfortunately I can't find any refernces to QQuickStyle class in PyQt to apply style via python code and only working solution is to specify command line argument for this:

```
python app.py -style material
```

Could someone point me to the correct applying QuickControls style via python script please?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Trying to do this as well.

Answer (score 13):

I am looking for QQuickStyle too, PyQt seem doesn't has QQuickStyle class, but you can do this in code,

```
sys_argv = sys.argv
sys_argv += ['--style', 'material']
app = QGuiApplication(sys_argv)
```